# Print the contents of the super block

Tags: unix

I'm told to write a program in 'C' to print the contents of the 'super block'. Can anybody tell me how to read the contents of the super block. Which system call can be used to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of superblock do you mean? The ext3 superblock?

Comment: They have not specified anything as such!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what they want you to do is precisely to find this.

Hint: Googling "superblock linux" and pressing "I'm feeling lucky" got me straight to the first links to the answers. (Yes, there are several :) )!

Hint hint: If the fs is extN, there is a catch!

Comment: Another hint: I don't think there is a syscall to read the superblock, but once you have figured out where the superblock is and what structure(s) it contains, starting by opening the raw disk partition containing the superblock will help!